# Vue span value from methods

Tags: vue.js

I want to get the value from methods and put this value in span element

There is my pseudo code and I don't know what is the right way to do that. Maybe stored in data?

```
<li v-for="item in items">
  <span>{{I want this value is from methods}} getValue(item)</span>
</li>

methods: {
    getValue: function(value){  
        return "value form methods" + value
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain better. It is totally unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: I want to use method to get the value which place in <span>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple like that:

```
<li v-for="item in items">
  <span>{{ getValue(item) }} </span>
</li>

methods: {
    getValue: function(value){  
        return "value form methods" + value
    }
}
```

Please do better with your questions quality.

Comment: Oh..I don't know the double curly brackets could use for methods. I think it's for data. Thank you